# Взаимодействие двух JS скриптов

Tags: javascript

Привет. Имеется страничка, к ней подключены два js файла. В каждом свой код:
 1. http://jsfiddle.net/754aE/
 2. http://jsfiddle.net/ssLu2/

Отдельно они прекрасно работают. Но стоит их объединить в 1 JS файл, ничего не работает. Как правильно их объединить подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: а html дадите?

Comment: открывайте консоль, смотрите ошибки

Comment: Причем тут ошибки, когда они вместе, такое ощущение, что кода будто не существует.

Comment: @js_cbs, вы не поверите, но я все-таки знаю, о чем говорю. Скорее всего у вас какой-то конфликт скриптов (например, переопределение важной переменной), которая не позволяет коду выполниться, в результате чего бракуется (не выполняется дальше) весь файл целиком. Потому вы и не видите никакого выполнения.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо

Comment: 1. За код в http://jsfiddle.net/ssLu2/ надо бить линейкой по рукам. Вы же полключили jquery. Зачем тогда вот так:

    var obj = document.getElementById("current");
    obj.src = src;

?

2. В том месте, где считаете, что код долден выполниться, но не выполняется, поставьте слово

    debugger;

это заставит браузер (Firefox, Chrome) остановиться в режиме пошаговой отладки. Проверьте логику, изучив значения переменных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ssLu2/
Заверните все функции как и в первом случае в $(document).ready(function(){...}).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jshint.com/ посмотрел тут, вроде все норм. Покажи как ты их "объединяешь" ?